# Google Chrome - How to change Bookmark file location?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to change my google chrome bookmark file to my dropbox so that I can use it on multiple computers. Is there any way>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply sign in to a Google Account in Chrome settings.

Your bookmarks (and extensions, and all other settings) will then automatically be shared among all computers and mobile devices.